# $(a \vee b)\wedge c=b\wedge c$ implies $(c\wedge b)\wedge a= b \vee c$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, integer-lattices

Show that for any elements a,b,c in a modular lattice $(a \vee b)\wedge c=b\wedge c$ implies $(c\wedge b)\wedge a= b \vee c$ ?
$\wedge$ is meet and $\vee$ is join operations respectively .

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please do provide some background for your questions, and indicate what you have tried and where you got stuck. This is not a homework answering service, but you will find people eager to help if you show some effort of your own. Also, I recommend learning a small bit of LaTeX, so you can write mathematics properly.

Answer (score 0):

The announced result is wrong. Consider the modular lattice $(\mathbb{R}, \max, \min)$ and $b = 1$, $a = c = 0$. Isn't there a typo?